# Enable Edit button if new record exists

Tags: javascript, php

I created a modal where I can insert new client record and edit the same record. But in relation to the edit button, I wanted it to be active only when there was a new record in the database and until the end of the day it was registered.

```
<a type="button" name="editar" id="'.$row["IdCliente"].'" data-toggle="modal" href="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-primary edit_data">Update</a>
```

I'm trying this way:

```
if(isset($_POST["employee_id3"]))  
 { 

$output = '';
$query = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.PsicUtentes LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.PsicUtentesConsulta ON centrodb.PsicUtentesConsulta.CodigoUtente2 = centrodb.PsicUtentes.CodigoUtente WHERE centrodb.PsicUtentes.Id = '".$_POST["employee_id3"]."' ORDER BY IdConsulta DESC ";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
      $output;
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {
          $dataAtual = DATE('Y-m-d');
          $disabled = "";

          if(DATE($row['Data2'])!=$dataAtual){
          $disabled = "disabled"; 
          }
           $output .= '



                     <h4 class="modal-title">Histórico de Consultas</h4> 
                    <div> 
                    <button type="button" class="exibir botao" href="#" aria-hidden="true">+</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" href="#" class="ocultar botao" aria-hidden="true">-</button> 
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="conteudo">
                    <form method="post" id="insert_form6">
                        <div style="float:right">  
                        <a type="button" name="edit3" id="'.$row["Id"].','.$row["IdConsulta"].'" data-toggle="modal" href="#add_data_Modal3" class="btn btn-primary edit_data3" "$disabled">Editar</a>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <fieldset class="grupo">
                        <table class="campo" cellspacing="10">
                         <tr>
                         <td>               

                           <input type="Hidden" id="IdConsulta1" name="IdConsulta" class="form-control" value="'.$row["IdConsulta"].'" style="width:150px;" readonly="true" />  
                          </td>
                          <td>              
                           <label>Data Consulta</label> 
                           <input type="text" id="Data23" name="Data2" class="form-control" value="'.$row["Data2"].'" style="width:150px;" readonly="true" />  
                          </td> 
                          <td>                        
                           <label>Código Utente</label> 
                           <input type="number" id="CodigoUtente5" name="CodigoUtente" value="'.$row["CodigoUtente"].'" class="form-control" style="width:100px;" readonly="true"/> 
                          </td>
                          <td>                        
                          <label>Nome Utente</label>  
                          <input type="text" id="Nome5" name="Nome" value="'.$row["Nome"].'" class="form-control" style="width:400px;" readonly="true"/>   
                          </td>
                          <td>  
                          <label>Data Nascimento</label>  
                          <input type="date" id="DataNasc5" name="DataNasc" value="'.$row["DataNasc"].'" class="form-control" style="width:150px;" readonly="true"/>   
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="grupo">
                        <table class="campo" cellspacing="10">
                         <tr>
                          <td>
                          <label>Data Admissao</label>  
                          <input type="date" id="DataAdmissao5" name="DataAdmissao" value="'.$row["DataAdmissao"].'" class="form-control" style="width:150px;" readonly="true"/>   
                          </td>
                          <td>
                          <label>Valência</label>  
                          <input type="text" id="ValenciasDescricao5" name="ValenciasDescricao" value="'.$row["ValenciasDescricao"].'" class="form-control" style="width:200px;" readonly="true"/>   
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="grupo">
                        <table class="campo" cellspacing="10">
                         <tr>
                          <td>
                          <label>Observação</label>
                          </p><textarea rows="6" cols="130" readonly="true">'.$row["Descricao"].'</textarea>                          
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="grupo">
                        <table class="campo" cellspacing="10">
                         <tr>                       
                           <td>
                           <label>O Psicologo/a</label>  
                          <input type="text" id="Colaborador2" name="Colaborador2" class="form-control" style="width:150px;"  value="'.$row["Colaborador2"].'" readonly="true"/>
                           </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        </fieldset>
                     </form>  
                </div>  


           ';  
      } 

      $output;  
      echo $output;  
 } 

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data3', function(){  
           var employee_id3 = $(this).attr("Id");          
           $.ajax({  
                url:"./fetch2",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id3:employee_id3},               
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){  

                     $('#IdConsulta').val(data.IdConsulta);
                     $('#Data22').val(data.Data2);                       
                     $('#CodigoUtente6').val(data.CodigoUtente2);
                     $('#Descricao1').val(data.Descricao);
                     $('#Colaborador2').val(data.Colaborador2);
                     $('#employee_id3').val(data.Id);                    
                     $('#insert3').val("Gravar");  
                     $('#add_data_Modal3').modal('show');

                }  
           });  
      });  

        $('#insert_form7').on("submit", function(event){  
           event.preventDefault(); 
           if($('#CodigoUtente6').val() == "")  
           {  
                alert("Código Utente é necessário");  
           }           
           else if($('#Descricao1').val() == "")  
           {  
                alert("Observação é necessária");  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:".conexao9",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#insert_form7').serialize()
                     ,  
                         beforeSend:function(){  

                          $('#insert3').val("Inserting");  
                     },                  
                     success:function(data){ 

                          $('#insert_form7')[0].reset();  
                          $('#add_data_Modal3').modal('hide');  
                          $('#employee_table').html(data); 
                          location.reload("add_data_Modal3");                         
                     }

                });  
           }  
      });     
 }); 
</script>
```

I created a variable with the current date that compares with the date of the record. I created an empty disabled variable. There I put this disabled variable in the link. If the date is different than the current date you put the disabled variable filled.The problem is that the button stays in the same asset.

Comment: You are checking if it the dates are not equal not if one is greater than the other. Echo `DATE($row['Data2'])` and `$dataAtual` to check what their values are

Comment: @Dimitris Filippou was wrong, I wanted to say different and because I was initially comparing one larger than another. 
I do `var_dump` to the variables and I get the values ​​I want, but the button is always null, and when the variable `$disabled` received the disabled value should deactivate the button

Comment: Can you post your desired output and the output that the above code produces? Also you have some syntax errors in your code.

Comment: @Dimitris Filippou  You want me to explain or put the complete code

Comment: Put the complete code. The above code is incomplete and has syntax errors. You never closed the php with `?>` before writing html and then you use `id="'.$row["Id"].','.$row["IdConsulta"].'"` in html which is wrong. Also you are echoing inputs with fixed ids inside a while (like `id="IdConsulta1"`) which in case your sql results are more than one it will produce invalid html.

Comment: @Dimitris Filippou I put the complete code on this page, then on another page I have the code that returns the data from the `fetch2` database and on `conxao9` is where I do the update or insert in the database table

Comment: Change `"$disabled"` to `'.$disabled.'` Also what is the purpose of this `$output;` appearing twice in your code? Delete both lines. And finally you have to close the php `?>` before the `<script>` tag. But all these doesn't solve the invalid html in case of more than 1 results from you query. Lastly you should use prepared statements as you code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: @Dimitris Filippou Regarding Sql injection attacks I will change the code. In html it will never return more than one result, because the id is unique with `$ _POST [" employee_id3 "]`. Regarding your answer worked correctly. Thank you

Comment: I posted the comments as an answer if your code is now working you can close the question if you want.

Comment: @Dimitris Filippou I already gave it as closed. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks and you should use prepared statements.

Then you have some syntax errors on your code.

The lines `$output;` are useless, delete them.
Change `"$disabled"` to `'.$disabled'.`
and put `?>` before your `<script>` tag.